# node.js \ how to run my periodic task and avoid collisions

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks

I have node.js process that should run every X seconds. thing is - I don't want to start the next iteration if current is not finished yet.

What would be elegent? see if process has two instances at the beginning of the code? seems kinda lame.. is there some node.js package that can be configured with that and will manage my task?

Comment: You can run next timer on prev process finish. Also you can count elapsed time by process.

Comment: How are you starting those processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you want to run some task in a loop in an asynchronous way. You can use 'async' module for this. Otherwise, if you don't want to use any modules, you should be using callbacks for your purpose.

```
var arr = [...]
function A(i) {
  if( i < arr.length ) {
    some_process( arr[i], function(err) {
      if( err ) {
        console.log('error: '+err)
      }
      else {
        A(i+1)
      }
    })
  }
}
A(0)
```

You can also use 'setInterval' for setting up a time interval between the processes. You can even use 'sleep' npm module for setting up time intervals between processes. Hope this works for you :)